# Error en db.SaveChangesAsync();

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Tengo un view donde edito datos y a la  hora de guardar cambios me marca error en la linea del await db.SaveChangesAsync();

Adjunto la funcion.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "LaptopId,Nombre,ProcesadorId,RAMId,CantidadRAM,UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoRAMId,DiscoDuro1Id,TamañoDiscoDuro1,UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoDiscoDuro1,DiscoDuro2Id,TamañoDiscoDuro2,UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoDiscoDuro2,SistemaOperativoId,Pulgadas,ClienteId,SucursalId,MarcaId,ModeloId,Serie,Activo")] Laptop laptop)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    db.Entry(laptop).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Clientes.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "ClienteId", "Nombre", laptop.ClienteId);
            ViewBag.DiscoDuro1Id = new SelectList(db.DiscosDuros.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "DiscoDuroId", "Nombre", laptop.DiscoDuro1Id);
            ViewBag.DiscoDuro2Id = new SelectList(db.DiscosDuros.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "DiscoDuroId", "Nombre", laptop.DiscoDuro2Id);
            ViewBag.MarcaId = new SelectList(db.Marcas.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "MarcaId", "Nombre", laptop.MarcaId);
            ViewBag.ModeloId = new SelectList(db.Modelos.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "ModeloId", "Nombre", laptop.ModeloId);
            ViewBag.ProcesadorId = new SelectList(db.Procesadores.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "ProcesadorId", "Nombre", laptop.ProcesadorId);
            ViewBag.RAMId = new SelectList(db.RAMs.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "RAMId", "Nombre", laptop.RAMId);
            ViewBag.SistemaOperativoId = new SelectList(db.SistemaOperativos.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "SistemaOperativoId", "Nombre", laptop.SistemaOperativoId);
            ViewBag.SucursalId = new SelectList(db.Sucursales.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "SucursalId", "Nombre", laptop.SucursalId);
            ViewBag.UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoRAMId = new SelectList(db.UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientos.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoId", "Nombre", laptop.UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoRAMId);
            ViewBag.UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoDiscoDuro1 = new SelectList(db.UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientos.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoId", "Nombre", laptop.UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoDiscoDuro1);
            ViewBag.UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoDiscoDuro2 = new SelectList(db.UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientos.Where(x => x.Activo == true), "UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoId", "Nombre", laptop.UnidadMedidaAlmacenamientoDiscoDuro2);
            return View(laptop);
        }
```

Adjunto imagen del error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es simple: luego de la modificación, la cantidad de propiedades que modificas es ninguna (0), si le cambias al menos 1 propiedad, no te lanzará error. Si estás inicando con ASP.net MVC, este workshop te será de ayuda: https://youtu.be/6LZG76aLykY Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, lo tomare en cuenta

Comment: Por lo tanto, ¿cerramos la pregunta?

Comment: sí pero no me marca esa opción

Comment: Dos alternativas: 1. Esperar a que voten para cerrar la pregunta. 2. Eliminar la pregunta directamente. Opinión personal: elijo la primera, cosa que queda como constancia para futuros desarrolladores que tengan el mismo escenario y se pregunten lo mismo.